# unity3d : The type "task" exist in both Unity.Tasks and mscorelib

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-signin

I created a blank project with unity 2019.1.4f1. I imported the firebase SDK package for authentication and another google sign in package from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity/releases). I am basically trying to achieve google signin in android with firebase. But when I import the 2nd package ( google sign in), I get this error (below)

I haven't done anything else in the project, just imported. I have no idea what to do.

> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.1\Scripts\Editor\TMP_PackageUtilities.cs(310,17):
>   error CS0433: The type 'Task' exists in both 'Unity.Tasks,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Answer (score 46):

its simple,

goto:
youProjectFolder\Assets\Parse\Plugins

remove all files outside of the dotNet45 Folder

[image: Image from your Project Foulder]

and the error should be solved.

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked for me in Unity 2020.2.

Comment: This was my issue I had two dll's in this folder after an upgrade from Unity 2019

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. (Unity 2021, Firebase 8.1)

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. (Unity 2021.3, Firebase 9)

Comment: If you still have errors in Visual Studio after *disabling* the DLLs outside `dotNet45` via Unity's import settings, make sure to *delete* the files. Visual Studio seems to pick them up by mistake.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue and fixed it. Looks like this version of TextMeshPro references all of the libraries in your project. You can change that by changing the cached package files. More precisely, you can add this line

`"overrideReferences": true,`

to

> "(Your Project Directory)\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.1\Scripts\Editor
> Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor.asmdef"

by opening it in a text editor (make sure you have access rights to write to the file).

That will make the TextMesh Pro Editor code reference only the assemblies in this file opposite to all of the compiled assemblies in the project.
the file will look like this:

```
    {
        "name": "Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor",
        "references": [
            "Unity.TextMeshPro",
            "Unity.ugui",
            "Unity.ugui.Editor"
        ],
        "optionalUnityReferences": [],
        "overrideReferences": true,
        "includePlatforms": [
            "Editor"
        ],
        "excludePlatforms": []
    }
```

The second option is to remove the TextMesh Pro Package. If you are sure that the project does not use it, you can use the top menu "Window -> Package Manager". Then in the Packages window, in the list select TextMesh Pro and click "Remove".

Comment: This is the only solution that works! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 11):

The issue that you may be running into is a compatibility layer that brings .NET 4.x features into .NET 3.x runtime called Parse. In Firebase, this is why there are dotnet3 and dotnet4 folders.

When you do your plugin imports, assuming that you're using the .NET 4.x runtime (default in Unity 2019), make sure that you grab the unity packages from the dotnet4 folder from Firebase. Then, when you import the Google SSO package, exclude the Parse directory (the Firebase plugin should have pulled in the necessary parts already anyway). That should get you up and running!

Answer (score 1):

Just update the textMeshPro from package manager.

Comment: This is what worked for me. See instructions on how to upgrade TextMeshPro from the package manager here on the Unity help page https://answers.unity.com/questions/1624399/textmeshpro-20-error-cs0433.html

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Ronny Bigler's answer, but a little clarification (sorry, I'm not able to comment yet).

You don't have to delete ALL of the files outside the dotNet45 folder. You need to delete the Unity.Compat.dll and the Unity.Tasks.dll. If these are all you have, then sure you can delete ALL files outside the dotNet45. But if you have other things there too, they do not need to be deleted.

It's also worth mentioning that I was only importing the google sign-in package, not the firebase one. So I didn't have the dotNet45 folder at all. But deleting the Compat and Tasks dlls did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Add a namespace to the declaration.

```
SomeNameSpace.Task task = new SomeNameSpace.Task();
```

e.g.

```
Unity.Tasks.Task task = new Unity.Tasks.Task();
```

Done.

Comment: Doesn't work here because they are both in the System.Threading.Tasks namespace.

Comment: 'Unity.Tasks, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Would argue, you are wrong about that?

Comment: Unity.Tasks and mscorlib are assembly names there, not namespace names. It's perfectly valid to have a class be in a namespace named differently to the assembly name.

Comment: So you are saying that there is a cyclic relationship between his own program and the imported assembly in unity?

I find that highly unlikely?

Or are you saying that simply importing an assembly from unity will cause a compile time error?