# Unity: Migrating to 2019.2.0f1 got error The type 'Task<T>' exists in both Unity.Tasks and mscorlib

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine

I have an existing project. It uses Firebase sdk and many more.
I already previously upgraded my project to Unity 2019.1.11f1 with no problems.
When i upgraded it to Unity 2019.2.0f1 i got error messages:
`error CS0433: The type 'Task<T>' exists in both 'Unity.Tasks, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'`

I already searched possible solutions with no results.
My project is using  .NET 2.0 compatibility level.

Does anyone stumbleupon similar issue?

Comment: Check answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422962/unity3d-the-type-task-exist-in-both-unity-tasks-and-mscorelib

Comment: @Renat Already checked that question. There is no valid answer for my question. Im not using .net 4.5 and my project was working perfectly fine on previous Unity version.

Comment: I think you maybe confused, 2019 and 2019.1 still I think allowed compilation with .net 3.5, but it was depreciated, now 2019.2 is only .net 4, the compatibility api maybe 2.0, but it is still compiled in .net 4 "We’ve removed the old .NET 3.5 Equivalent Scripting Runtime. Any projects that use the .NET 3.5 Equivalent Scripting Runtime will be automatically updated to use the .NET 4.x Equivalent Scripting Runtime." taken from [unity blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/07/30/heres-whats-in-the-brand-new-unity-2019-2/)

Comment: @BugFinder oh, i see. now it's all make sense. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that `Task<T>` is referenced in two (or more) of your assemblies. In this case in the directives:

```
using Unity.Tasks;
using mscorlib`;
```

There are several things you can do. The first would be to remove one of the directives if possible (this can ofcourse only be done if either of the two is unused. So not always possible). Alternatively you can specify that `Task<T>` needs to reference a specific assembly by doing

```cs
using Task<T> = Unity.Task;
```

Another option is to inline declare from which directive you want to use `Task<T>`. For example `Unity.Task.Task<T> = foo;` or `mscorlib.Task<T> = bar;`. This will clear up the ambiguity for the compiler.

(both of the above options should have been picked up by visual studio if you are using VS. hover over the red underline and select "show potential fixes" or `ctrl + .` by default)

A final solution is to use the `/reference` compiler option. as shown in the microsoft [docs on error CS0433](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0433)
(example copied directly from above docs)

```cs
// compile with: /reference:cs0433_1.dll /reference:TypeBindConflicts=cs0433_2.dll  
using TypeBindConflicts;  
public class Test   
{  
   public static void Main()   
   {  
      AggPubImpAggPubImp n6 = new AggPubImpAggPubImp();  
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have Unity.compat and Unity.tasks at root of Assets/Parse/Plugins and also under a dotNet45 folder there, delete the files at the root.